# JSON Data Load into in memory database h2

Tags: json, h2, in-memory-database

I m trying to load json data into in memory database h2.

when i create datasource i have to set url where i m not getting to how to define path for json data file.

Need guidence.

Comment: I did successfully when i hav to load data from script and used below URL:


   url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MVCC=TRUE;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'C:/versions/tip/sqlscripts/create.sql'"

Comment: I would be interested in how does the JSON data file look like. Could you provide a few lines of data please?

Comment: {"paramSysRefs":{"id":1,"name":"MSS-Framing-Ref","system":"MSS","path":"mss://${server}/S:B T1 On-Net Facility Product{3372}/S:T1 Circuit{3373}/L:Rate Code"}}

Comment: Could be a case for [CSV cruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher) - if someone added that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [JSON parser](http://json.org/java/) to read and parse the JSON, and then use the [JDBC API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/index.html) to insert the data into the database.

With the JDBC API, make sure you use `PreparedStatement`, that means, create one `PreparedStatement` per table, and re-use those. What you could do is keep them in a map, one prepared statement per table (`Map<String, PreparedStatement>`).

Comment: @Thomas Mueller is there a reason behind using one prepStatement for each table? Just curious

Comment: @TomasBisciak well, how could you use one prepStatement for multiple tables?